# CoolProp in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, python, google-sheets, shared-libraries

I want to calculate fluid properties in google sheets. I tried to find information on this, but was not very successful.

https://groups.google.com/g/coolprop-users/c/9j-SaHsz3oc
https://groups.google.com/g/coolprop-users/c/oqWCrb0YV5Y/m/ilx2hekgAgAJ

Would like to know what would be the best way to approach this.

One approach that I can think of is to create a API and query the API from an AppScript.

Would like to know if there are any other alternative approaches that are possible.

- CoolProp has a wrappers for python and Javascript. Is there a way to call this in Google AppScript?
- Or is it possible to call a shared library or compiled code in google AppScript?